# Thymeleaf - How to write Html string literals?

Tags: thymeleaf

How can we write HTML and string literals at a same time in Thymeleaf ?

```
<div class="details"><span class="Section" th:utext="'Sec' <br> ${wind.sec}"></span><span class="Axiom" th:utext="'Axiom' <br> ${wind.axiom}"></span></div>
```

This throws error

```
Cannot execute GREATER THAN from Expression "('Sec' < br) > ${wind.sec}". Left is "true", right is "Great"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following = which uses `+` for string concatenation:

```
<div class="details">
    <span class="Section" th:utext="'Sec<br>' + ${wind.sec}"></span>
    <span class="Axiom" th:utext="'Axiom<br>' + ${wind.axiom}"></span>
</div>
```

The `<br>` is just part of the text literal in this case - because you are using `th:utext`.

However, using unescaped values such as `${wind.sec}` is **unsafe** and is **not recommended**. There could be harmful values in that variable - especially if the variable holds data provided by end users.

So, unless the following structure change poses a problem, I would recommend something like this:

```
<div class="details">
    <span class="Section" th:utext="'Sec<br>'"></span>
    <span class="Section" th:text="${wind.sec}"></span>
    <span class="Axiom" th:utext="'Axiom<br>'"></span>
    <span class="Axiom" th:text="${wind.axiom}"></span>
</div>
```

Here we have separated the true text literals (which can use `th:utext`) from the variables (which should use `th:text`). Now, any HTML which may have found its way into your `${...}` variables will be escaped, rendering it harmless.